# How do I install python 3.6.1 on redhat for my user account without impacting an existing python 2.7.6 install?

Tags: rhel, python

This is the output that I have from the server that I'm working with. Some existing scripts are using python 2.7.6, but the ones that I'm trying to get up and running have been written in python 3.6.1.

```
[username@servername ~]$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 27 2015, 16:22:20)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
[username@servername ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
[username@servername ~]$ which python3
/usr/bin/which: no python3 in (/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/username/bin)
```

Comment: best option will be to use virtualenv https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Comment: Anaconda should do the job well - https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to install using command line as shown below

sudo yum install python36

This will install python 3.6.1 to /usr/bin/python36

Check my output below:

[xxx ~]$ which python

/usr/bin/python

[xxx ~]$ which python36

/usr/bin/python36

[xxx ~]$ python36

Python 3.6.1 (default, May 11 2017, 13:02:16) 
[GCC 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > 

Comment: Would this impact the existing python 2.7.6 install?

Comment: This is from the EPEL repo. You'll need to install that first. It won't impact the existing python 2.7.6 install.

Answer (score 0):

The [IUS repo](https://ius.io/) has a parallel installable [python 3.6 package](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/7/x86_64/repoview/python36u.html). This will not touch the system python, `/usr/bin/python` will still be the RHEL python package, `/usr/bin/python36` will be the python 3.6 package.